# Programmatically get fieldnames to populate a table/crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In relation to my question of [transposing rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561422/transpose-a-set-of-values-in-rows-to-columns-in-access-2010), what if there are over 100 "tests," can we write a VBA code to programmatically get the fieldname in the recordset and use it as data in the new table?

To illustrate, convert

```
|   ID   |   Date   |  Test1  |... |  Test200  |
|   1    |   Date1  |   10    |... |     34    |
|   1    |   Date2  |   14    |... |     53    |
|   2    |   Date1  |   23    |... |     43    |
```

into

```
ID = 1
         |  Date 1  |  Date2  |
Test1    |    10    |   14    |
...
Test200  |    34    |   53    |

ID = 2
         |  Date 1  |
Test1    |    23    |
...
Test200  |    43    |
```

The fieldnames are not formatted like Test[i] where i is 1 to 200. Test names are very varied. Any response would be brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a form that lists the available tests and the associated field name and use that to programmatically build the queries you need using VBA.

Comment: Say something if you get stuck.

Comment: I was stuck. I ended up writing the entire SQL query. And in the process, discovered that SQL can handle a limited PIVOT, ending up being told that my query is too complex.

Comment: The general idea was to follow my previous answer and use that outline to create your sql. If you would like to post some code or your sql either here or in a new thread, someone can help you, I am sure. I will certainly try.